# how can i make a simple wep key generator in javascript?

Tags: javascript, generator, wep

im trying to make a wep key generator and ive read how wep keys work but i really dont even know how to start making it. can anyone give me an example or direct me to a tutorial? i tried using google but no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in javascript...

```js
function generateHexString(length) {
  // Use crypto.getRandomValues if available
  if (
    typeof crypto !== 'undefined' 
    && typeof crypto.getRandomValues === 'function'
  ) {
    var tmp = new Uint8Array(Math.max((~~length)/2));
    crypto.getRandomValues(tmp);
    return Array.from(tmp)
      .map(n => ('0'+n.toString(16)).substr(-2))
      .join('')
      .substr(0,length);
  }

  // fallback to Math.getRandomValues
  var ret = "";
  while (ret.length < length) {
    ret += Math.random().toString(16).substring(2);
  }
  return ret.substring(0,length);
}

// 40-/64-bit WEP: 10 digit key
alert("40-bit:" + generateHexString(10));

// 104-/128-bit WEP: 26 digit key
alert("104-bit:" + generateHexString(26))

// 256-bit WEP: 58 digit key
alert("256-bit:" + generateHexString(58));
```

If you wanted to generate something based on a fixed string input, there are methods for doing that as well... this should give you what you are looking for in terms of just a straight random hex string of the correct length.

I'm not sure if there is a standard passphrase to WEP generator, but most limit the input to printable characters, and the algorythms are generally weak.. best bet is to simply use WPA2PSK if you can.

Comment: avoid omitting the curly braces in javascript, that will save you debugging time.