# Is it possible to distribute app. only for selected accounts/clients

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to distribute app. only for selected accounts/clients on Android Market or maybe there is other easy way of distribution only to selected users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just give them the apk.
Or if you want to you could make the app available to everyone but can only be accessed with validation key. Key Generators are relatively simple to make there's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5398737/how-can-i-make-a-simple-wep-key-generator-in-javascript).